# Using sys.argv from another .py file - python

Tags: python, bash, argv, sys

I have a file (test.py) that receives `sys.argv` from the console/bash:

```
import sys

def main():
    ans = int(sys.argv[1])**int(sys.argv[1])
    with open('test.out', 'w') as fout:
        fout.write(str(ans))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Usually, I could just do `$ python test.py 2` to produce the `test.out` file. But I need to call the `main()` function from test.py from another script.

I could do as below in (`call.py`) but **is there any other way to run pass an argument to `sys.argv` to `main()` in `test.py?**

```
import os

number = 2
os.system('python test.py '+str(number))
```

Please note that I **CANNOT** modify `test.py` and I also have a main() in `call.py` which does other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your program as it is. Because, irrespective of the file invoked by python, all the python files will get the command line arguments passed.

But you can make the `main` function accept `sys.argv` as the default parameter. So, `main` will always take the `sys.argv` by default. When you pass a different list, it will take the first element and process it.

#### test.py

```
import sys

def main(args = sys.argv):
    ans = int(args[1])**int(args[1])
    with open('test.out', 'w') as fout:
        fout.write(str(ans))
```

#### call.py

```
import sys, test
test.main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Without modifying `test.py` you can still run it just as you have it, just do `call.py:`

```
import test

test.main()
```

then `$ python call.py ARG` will still work. Since you've already imported `sys` in test, you don't need to reimport it unless you want to use `sys` in `call.py`. Note that `sys.argv[0]=='call.py'` not `test.py` if use test through call.

Answer (score 2):

Write that like:

```
import sys

def main(num):
    ans = int(num)**int(num)
    with open('test.out', 'w') as fout:
        fout.write(str(ans))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

so that your `main()` function doesn't have to know about sys.argv - it just handles the parameters being passed in to it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to do your calculation and file writing, which can be called from any other module:

power.py:

```
import sys

def power(arg):    
    ans = arg ** arg
    with open('test.out', 'w') as fout:
        fout.write(str(ans))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    power(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

other.py:

```
import power

power.power(2)
```